# Fetching the email body by the send grid message Id

Tags: node.js, smtp, sendgrid, implementation

Is there any way we can fetch the email body by the send grid message Id( which is looks like this QpnPqIzvS-u9ZdGIyNrFOw.filterdrecv-59cb65cf6d-kpcxt-1-63FDCB99-11.0). Please let me know. How to implement in the NodeJS using @sendgrid/mail package

I am not aware. I am new to send grid

Answer (score 1):

No, afaik, SendGrid doesn't store the sent emails in an outbox. [The answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042659/how-can-i-search-for-past-sent-emails-with-sendgrid) under this question might be able to help you too.

You can use the [Activity API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/email-activity-feed) for up to 7 days if you would like to see metadata of the email.

If you really need to store the email content, please refer to this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210612150632/https://sendgrid.com/blog/%E2%80%8Bhow-to-store-the-contents-of-emails-sent-via-sendgrid/) to see how you can build this on top of SendGrid.